# Como customizar as borda laterais de uma DIV?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma `<div>` cuja borda tem uma customização diferente do padrão. Ela não é totalmente sólida, ela tem "espaços" abertos na parte superior e na parte inferior.

Exemplo desenhado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O conteúdo central varia, então o tamanho da `<div>` também varia.

O que já tentei:

- Criei 2 `<div>`, uma embaixo com a borda sólida e a outra em cima com o fundo branco, porém, não ficou prático;
- Utilizei pseudo-elementos para alocar a borda na direita e na esquerda, mas também não ficou legal por causa que o tamanho varia;
- Usei `border-image`, mas também não ficou bom.

Alguém tem sugestão?

Comment: Mas essa parte sem borda é ocupada por um texto? Seria um título do que terá dentro da div?
Se sim, usa background no elemento h ou p que terá o título e posiciona ele usando position, z-index e margin.
Mas põe o código aí pra ficar mais fácil.
Se quiser deixar mais fácil a ajuda, põe no http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @VítorAndré sim, o conteúdo da box varia. As vezes tem um título no topo e um texto no meio, ou as vezes são 3 palavras listadas. Mas o layout da borda é esse, com as partes centrais "em branco". Na verdade vai ter casos que somente a parte superior fica em branco, o restante a borda permanece sólida.

Comment: Não é como esta o exemplo mas pelo seu comentario não pretende um fieldset?

Comment: Pow pessoal, não lembrava disso. Ele faz exatamente o que quero, muito obrigado. Vou testar aqui utilizando ele depois comento como ficou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pseudo-elementos são uma solução prática e rápida:

```css
.borda {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding:0 20px;       /* espaço nas laterais     */
  font-size:20px;
}

.borda:before,.borda:after {
  content:''; display:block;position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
  top:8px; bottom:8px; /* espaço no topo e embaixo */
  width:13px;          /* largura das "chaves"     */
}

.borda:before {
  left:2px; border-right:none;
}

.borda:after {
  right:2px; border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="borda">TEXTO</div>
<div class="borda">TEXTO<br>TEXTO<br><br>TEXTO<br>TEXTO<br><br>TEXTO</div>
<div class="borda">TEXTO<br>TEXTO<br>TEXTO<br>TEXTO</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Ricardo deixei nos comments os lugares chave para você ajustar as medidas. Só não comentei do `2px` no final, no `left` e `right` do final. Pode ser 0, se não precisar de espaço em branco entre divs diferentes. Pus aqueles `2px` pra não colar os 3 testes do exemplo.

Comment: Sim @Bacco eu utilizei seu código e ajustei para meu site.. ficou bom. Obrigado novamente \o/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ocultar as bordas utilizando CSS.

```css
 div{
   border-style: solid;
   border-bottom-style: none;
   border-top-style: none;
 }
```

No próprio documento HTML fica:

```html
<style>
 div{
   border-style: solid;
   border-bottom-style: none;
   border-top-style: none;
 }
</style>
```