# Como represento isso usando CSS?

Tags: html, css

Alguém tem uma dica de como posso representar isso usando HTML e CSS? Sem usar position absolute, apenas com borda ou outra coisa.

(Essa seria a imagem da arte que quero transcrever no css)

[image: Representação]

Comment: Tens HTML ou queres uma maneira para fazer isso de raiz?

Comment: Usando SVG - http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

Comment: Possivel duplicata dessa? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124251/como-customizar-as-borda-laterais-de-uma-div

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conteúdo bastante similar ao apresentado por @bacco em [Como customizar as borda laterais de uma DIV?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124251/como-customizar-as-borda-laterais-de-uma-div), porém esta utiliza pseudo-elementos para formar os marcadores horizontalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.clamp-container{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.clamp-text{
  margin:10px 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:40px;
}

.clamp-text:before{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-bottom-width:0;


  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  height:3px;


}

.clamp-text:after, .clamp-text:before{
  border:1px solid black;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  height:10%;
}

.clamp-text:before{
  border-bottom-width:0;
  top:0px;
}

.clamp-text:after{
  border-top-width:0;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<span class='clamp-container'><span class='clamp-text'>Empresa</span></span>
```

Comment: @Bacco Nem sabia da existência dessa...

Comment: Eu demorei um pouco pra achar tb. Só lembrei pq eu "participei" :)

Answer (score 5):

Meu exemplo com **z-index**.

***EDIT***: aliás, viagem minha, nem precisa do z-index porque é div dentro de div, não duas sobrepostas. Mas funciona do mesmo jeito.

```css
#main {border: 2px solid darkgrey; width: 200px; padding:15px 0;font: 25px Arial;text-align:center;background:white;}
#main div {background:white;width:204px;z-index:1;position:relative;left:-2px}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div>
EMPRESA
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa também, só precisa avisar que nesse caso não funciona com fundo texturizado ou com foto. É o mesmo caso que essa minha de pontilhado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165862/70 (outro problema, mas usando z-index)